# Output to elastisearch 2.3.3 from logstash 2.3.2 results in an error "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters"

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to follow a smiple [tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html). Running this simple config and typing a simple message results in an error:

```html
Failed action. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"logstash-2016.06.08", :_type=>"logs", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x7ab1f728 @metadata_acce
ssors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x6d2f9ce3 @store={}, @lut={}>, @cancelled=false, @data={"message"=>"Hellothere\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-06-08T20:14:07.588Z"
, "host"=>"MYMACHINE"}, @metadata={}, @accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x6619e823 @store={"message"=>"Hellothere\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-06-08T20:14:0
7.588Z", "host"=>"MYMACHINE"}, @lut={"host"=>[{"message"=>"Hellothere\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-06-08T20:14:07.588Z", "host"=>"MYMACHINE"}, "host"], "type"=
>[{"message"=>"Hellothere\r", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-06-08T20:14:07.588Z", "host"=>"MYMACHINE"}, "type"]}>>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-2016.06
.08", "_type"=>"logs", "_id"=>nil, "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"Failed to parse mapping [?date?]: Root mapping definition has unsupp
orted parameters:  [?store? : true]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [?store? : true]"}}}},
:level=>:warn}

{
       "message" => "Hellothere\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-06-08T20:14:07.588Z",
          "host" => "MYMACHINE"
}
```

Does it mean the Logstash 2.3.2 elasticsearch plugin is not up to date with the latest changes of Elasticsearch 2.3.3?

I am new to Elastic and Logstash.

Can this error be mitigated somehow?

Comment: Yes, previous version of Elasticsearch (2.3.2) does not have this problem.

Comment: Wish helps [Can not create Elasticsearch Index (logstash-2015.05.18)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39659004/898431)