# Can not create Elasticsearch Index (logstash-2015.05.18)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.4

Following the instruction from the Elasticsearch Kibana official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/4.5/getting-started.html), when I create the index `logstash-2015.05.18`, the error below were emitted.

```
# curl -XPUT http://10.15.0.70:9200/logstash-2015.05.18 -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "log": {
      "properties": {
        "geo": {
          "properties": {
            "coordinates": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
   }
  }
}
';


{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [“store” : true]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [“date”]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [“store” : true]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [“store” : true]"}},"status":400}
```

Using the `sense` plugin  of Kibana to create the index also gives me the same  error

```
PUT logstash-2015.05.18
{
  "mappings": {
    "log": {
      "properties": {
        "geo": {
          "properties": {
            "coordinates": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [“store” : true]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [“date”]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [“store” : true]",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
         "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [“store” : true]"
      }
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Can someone tell me did I do something wrong when creating the index?

Comment: Could it be that you're not using the proper double quote characters? See `“store”` (wrong) vs `"store"` (correct)

Answer (score 0):

Had same trouble.

Removing elasticsearch data("/usr/local/var/elasticsearch", if you install it with Homebrew) fixed it for me.